# Django ajax return a html page

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to decrypt encrypted text and return the plain text through ajax call, instead of getting the message response I get an HTML page back as a response. I have tried returning the response as JSON but still getting the same HTML response.

```
function loadMessage() {
        fetch("{% url 'chat:history' chatgroup.id %}")
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then( data => {
                for (let msg of data) {
                  var message=msg.message;
                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'GET',
                      url: '',
                      data: { message: message},
                      success: function(response){
                         broadcastMessage(response.message, msg.username, msg.date_created)

                      }
                    })                        
                }                    
            })
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def get(request):
message = request.GET.get('message')
key = b'\xa8|Bc\xf8\xba\xac\xca\xdc/5U0\xe3\xd6f'
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR)
nounce = b64encode(cipher.nonce).decode('utf-8')

if request.is_ajax():
    nounce_ = self.nounce
    msg_ = self.message
    key = self.key
    nounce = b64decode(nounce_)
    ct = b64decode(msg_)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nounce=nounce)
    msg_ = cipher.decrypt(ct)
    mwssage = msg_.decode()

    return JsonResponse({'message': message})

return render(request, 'chat/room.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The path to the decryption view was empty, after adding a path in the url it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).